# African language typo

Tags: fonts, fontspec, overleaf, typography

please need to write this special caracter in latex:

```
(b, ɓ, c, d, ɗ, f, g, h, j, k, l, m, n, ny, ŋ, p, r, s, t, w, y, ƴ,’ mb, nd, ng, nj)''
```

thank for your help.

```
Table 6: Letters Used to Typeset African Languages
Ð \B{D} ° \m{c} ¤ \m{f} ¨ \m{k} » \M{t}  \m{Z}
ž \B{d}  \m{D} „ \m{F}  \m{N} › \M{T} Â \T{E}
‡ \B{H} ð \M{d} † \m{G} ­ \m{n} º \m{t} â \T{e}
§ \B{h} Ð \M{D} ¦ \m{g} ª \m{o} š \m{T} Å \T{O}
· \B{t} ¡ \m{d} À \m{I} Š \m{O} ® \m{u}∗
å \T{o}
 \B{T} ‚ \m{E} à \m{i} ‘ \m{P} Ž \m{U}∗
  \m{b} ¢ \m{e} ‰ \m{J} ± \m{p}  \m{Y}
€ \m{B} ƒ \M{E} © \m{j} ¬ \m{s} ¯ \m{y}
 \m{C} £ \M{e} ˆ \m{K} Œ \m{S} ¶ \m{z}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

They are quite common characters available in most fonts. If I typeset this example extracted from your question

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\begin{document}

b, ɓ, c, d, ɗ, f, g, h, j, k, l, m, n, ny, ŋ, p, r, s, t, w, y, ƴ,’ mb, nd, ng, nj

Ð  °  ¤  ¨  »   
ž    „    ›  Â 
‡  ð  †  ­  º  â 
§  Ð  ¦  ª  š  Å 
·  ¡  À  Š  ® ∗
å 
  ‚  à  ‘  Ž ∗
   ¢  ‰  ±   
€  ƒ  ©  ¬  ¯ 
  £  ˆ  Œ  ¶ 


\end{document}
```

There is just one missing character

```
There is no ∗ (U+2217) in font TimesNewRoman:mode=node;script=latn;language=dflt;+tlig;!
```

so if I use instead a normal `*` to get

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\begin{document}

b, ɓ, c, d, ɗ, f, g, h, j, k, l, m, n, ny, ŋ, p, r, s, t, w, y, ƴ,’ mb, nd, ng, nj

Ð  °  ¤  ¨  »   
ž    „    ›  Â 
‡  ð  †  ­  º  â 
§  Ð  ¦  ª  š  Å 
·  ¡  À  Š  ® *
å 
  ‚  à  ‘  Ž *
   ¢  ‰  ±   
€  ƒ  ©  ¬  ¯ 
  £  ˆ  Œ  ¶ 


\end{document}
```

Then it runs with lualatex or xelatex without error and produces

[image]

Comment: Tank , need to add this special caracter in the middle of text.

Comment: @ZouleihaAlhadji yes they can be used just the way you would use `abc` I just copied your table letters as I do not know what words you want, but no special markup is needed.

Comment: You can use `\newunicodechar{^^^^2217}{*}`, from `newunicodechar`, if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I would use Unicode fonts where you can, like in David Carlisle’s excellent answer, and 8-bit legacy font encodings where you have to. But, if you must use PDFTeX, the symbols you are looking for are in the legacy T4 encoding.

```
\documentclass{article}
\tracinglostchars=3
\usepackage[T4, T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}

\DeclareTextSymbolDefault\textbhook{T4}
\DeclareTextSymbolDefault\textdhook{T4}
\DeclareTextSymbolDefault\textyhook{T4}

\begin{document}


b, ɓ, c, d, ɗ, f, g, h, j, k, l, m, n, ny, ŋ, p, r, s, t, w, y, ƴ,' mb, nd, ng, nj

Ð  °  ¤  ¨  »   
ž    „    ›  Â 
‡  ð  †  ­  º  â 
§  Ð  ¦  ª  š  Å 
·  ¡  À  Š  ® ∗
å 
  ‚  à  ‘  Ž ∗
   ¢  ‰  ±   
€  ƒ  ©  ¬  ¯ 
  £  ˆ  Œ  ¶ 
\end{document}
```

If you get an error such as `There is no ∗ (U+2217) in font TimesNewRoman`, the solution is to add

```
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\newunicodechar{^^^^2217}{\textasterisk}
```

You could also use this to change the font, such as

```
\newunicodechar{^^^^2217}{{\symbolfont\symbol{"2217}}}
```

it is likely that, if you are using these symbols in actual text, and not merely displaying them in a table, you would want to load the language you are using in `babel` or `polyglossia`, which would let you change the font to one that supports your language.